# How to handle error responses using spring rest client

Tags: java, spring, http

I am trying to better handle bad responses when using the sprint rest client.  My code is as follows:

```
ResponseEntity<Foo> response = null;

try {
    response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET,
                       new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()), Foo.class);
catch (RestClientException rce) {
    //what to do here?
}
```

This works great as long as there is no error.  The problem is that when the corresponding web service returns an error (or times out), I just get an exception.  There is no enum with a status code where I could handle it as I wish.  Sometimes the error message is useful. Sometimes not.  Usually, if the corresponding server returns an html error page, I just get a message that the object cannot be created, but the specific error is swallowed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What can you get with `rce.getMostSpecificCause()`? Maybe there is some more information.

You can catch `HttpStatusCodeException` that is direct subclass of `RestClientException` which is more generic. There are a lot of exceptions that you can catch that are much more specific than `RestClientException` e.g.

```
public class HttpServerErrorException
extends HttpStatusCodeException

Exception thrown when an HTTP 5xx is received.
```

Look at the [docs for `RestClientException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientException.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the website you are querying returns an HTTP errorstatus then that should be reflected in the response object and you can switch through the statuses that you want to cover.

```
switch(response.getStatus()) {
  case HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST: {
  }
  case HTTPStatus.BAD_GATEWAY: {
  }
...
}
```

The RestClientException should only be thrown if there is a client side error, i.e. that's independent from the server response. ([Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientException.html))